# Persona in Passiv

Tags: passive

Meine Frage ist, wo man den Täter ins Passiv setzt. Hier zwei Beispiele aus dem Buch:

1. Früher sind **von den meisten Leuten** keine Reisen in fremde Länder gemacht worden.
2. Heute werden Einzelteile auf der ganzen Welt **von den Firmen** gekauft.

Ich verstehe nicht genau, wann man "von" vor dem Objekt und nach dem Objekt schreiben soll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die Position eines Satzgliedes im deutschen Satz legt fest, ob es sich im Kontext um eine bekannte Information oder um eine neue Information handelt. Schon Bekanntes sagt man zuerst, neues später.

> Früher sind von den meisten Leuten keine Reisen in fremde Länder gemacht worden.

Hier ist *von den meisten Leuten* eine eher unwichtige, als bekannt vorausgesetzte Information.

> Früher sind Reisen in fremde Länder von den meisten Leuten nicht gemacht worden.

Hier ist *von den meisten Leuten* eine wichtige Einschränkung, die vermutlich im nächsten Satz genauer erläutert wird. Ich habe im selben Zug auch die Negation verschieben müssen, denn die muss in diesem Zusammenhang  nah am Prädikat bleiben.

---

> Heute werden von den meisten Firmen Einzelteile auf der ganzen Welt gekauft.

Auch hier ist *von den meisten Firmen* wieder eine eher unwichtige, als bekannt vorausgesetzte Information.

> Heute werden Einzelteile auf der ganzen Welt von den meisten Firmen gekauft.

Während hier *von den meisten Firmen* wieder als wichtige neue Information markiert ist.